# CoreAudio AudioQueue stop issue

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiotoolbox, audioqueueservices

I'm making a CoreAudio based FLAC player, and ran into a naughty issue with AudioQueues. 
I'm initializing my stuff like this (variables beginning with an underscore are instance variables):

```
    _flacDecoder = FLAC__stream_decoder_new();

    AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd = {
        .mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        .mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked,
        .mSampleRate = 44100,
        .mChannelsPerFrame = 2,
        .mBitsPerChannel = 16,
        .mBytesPerPacket = 4,
        .mFramesPerPacket = 1,
        .mBytesPerFrame = 4,
        .mReserved = 0
    };

    AudioQueueNewOutput(&asbd, HandleOutputBuffer, (__bridge void *)(self), CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, &_audioQueue);

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(_audioQueue, 0x10000, &_audioQueueBuffers[i]);
    }

    AudioQueueSetParameter(_audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0);
```

16 bit stereo PCM at 44.1 kHz, pretty basic setup. kNumberBuffers is 3, and each buffer is 0x10000 bytes. 
I populate the buffers with these callbacks:

```
static void HandleOutputBuffer(void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer){

    FLACPlayer * self = (__bridge FLACPlayer*)inUserData;

    UInt32 largestBlockSizeInBytes = self->_currentStreamInfo.max_blocksize * self->_currentStreamInfo.channels * self->_currentStreamInfo.bits_per_sample/8;

    inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 0;
    self->_buffer = inBuffer;

    while(inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize <= inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity - largestBlockSizeInBytes){
        FLAC__bool result = FLAC__stream_decoder_process_single(self->_flacDecoder);
        assert(result);

        if(FLAC__stream_decoder_get_state(self->_flacDecoder) == FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_END_OF_STREAM){
            AudioQueueStop(self->_audioQueue, false);
            break;
        }
    }

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}

static FLAC__StreamDecoderWriteStatus flacDecoderWriteCallback(const FLAC__StreamDecoder *decoder, const FLAC__Frame *frame, const FLAC__int32 * const buffer[], void *client_data){

    FLACPlayer * self = (__bridge FLACPlayer *)client_data;

    assert(frame->header.bits_per_sample == 16); // TODO

    int16_t * bufferWritePosition = (int16_t*)((uint8_t*)self->_buffer->mAudioData + self->_buffer->mAudioDataByteSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < frame->header.blocksize; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < frame->header.channels; j++){
            *bufferWritePosition = (int16_t)buffer[j][i];
            bufferWritePosition++;
        }
    }

    int totalFramePayloadInBytes = frame->header.channels * frame->header.blocksize * frame->header.bits_per_sample/8;
    self->_buffer->mAudioDataByteSize += totalFramePayloadInBytes;

    return FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_WRITE_STATUS_CONTINUE;
}

static void flacDecoderMetadataCallback(const FLAC__StreamDecoder *decoder, const FLAC__StreamMetadata *metadata, void *client_data){

    FLACPlayer * self = (__bridge FLACPlayer*) client_data;

    if(metadata->type == FLAC__METADATA_TYPE_STREAMINFO){
        self->_currentStreamInfo = metadata->data.stream_info;
    }
}
```

Basically when the queue requests a new buffer, I fill the buffer from the FLAC__stream_decoder, then I enqueue it. Just like everyone else would do. When libFLAC tells me that I've reached the end of my file, I tell the AudioQueue to stop asynchronously, until it had consumed all the buffers' contents. However, instead of playing through the end, the playback stops a tiny bit before it should. If I remove this line:

```
AudioQueueStop(self->_audioQueue, false);
```

everything works fine; the audio plays end-to-end, although my queue keeps running till the end of time. If I change that line to this:

```
AudioQueueStop(self->_audioQueue, true);
```

then the playback stops immediately/synchronously, as you'd expect from Apple's documentation:

> *If you pass true, stopping occurs immediately (that is,
>   synchronously). If you pass false, the function returns immediately,
>   but the audio queue does not stop until its queued buffers are played
>   or recorded (that is, the stop occurs asynchronously). Audio queue
>   callbacks are invoked as necessary until the queue actually stops.*

My questions are:
- am I doing anything wrong?
- how can I play my audio until the end, and shut down the queue appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, after struggling with this stuff for hours, I've found the solution minutes after posting this question...
The problem was that the AudioQueue doesn't care about buffers enqueued *after* calling *AudioQueueStop(..., false)*. So now I'm feeding the queue like this, and everything works like charm:

```
static void HandleOutputBuffer(void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer){

    FLACPlayer * self = (__bridge FLACPlayer*)inUserData;

    UInt32 largestBlockSizeInBytes = self->_currentStreamInfo.max_blocksize * self->_currentStreamInfo.channels * self->_currentStreamInfo.bits_per_sample/8;

    inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 0;
    self->_buffer = inBuffer;

    bool shouldStop = false;

    while(inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize <= inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity - largestBlockSizeInBytes){
        FLAC__bool result = FLAC__stream_decoder_process_single(self->_flacDecoder);
        assert(result);

        if(FLAC__stream_decoder_get_state(self->_flacDecoder) == FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_END_OF_STREAM){
            shouldStop = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
    if(shouldStop){
        AudioQueueStop(self->_audioQueue, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not making sense - did you mean to say 

 "... AudioQueue doesn't care about buffers enqueued **AFTER** calling AudioQueueStop ....".

I think every buffer enqueued before the queue is stopped will be played.